# computer control for Yaesu FT-450

Tags: yaesu, remote-control, computer-control, ft-450d

I just acquired a Yaesu FT-450 and am interested in what it can do when connected to my PC.

I see that there is programming software available with which one can load information into the 450's memory from a spreadsheet-like file, which would be much easier than keying the data in via the buttons on the 450 front panel.

But does anybody know if there is a program available which essentially emulates a software-defined radio for the 450- that is, something that maps all the control functionality of the 450 onto the screen of the 450, so it can be operated in real-time through the keyboard and mouse?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of an application that has full control of every feature. However, there are a variety of applications available that work for basic functions. [FLRIG](http://www.w1hkj.com/flrig-help/) will give you many of the most common features. I use the related program, FLDigi, for operating digital modes with my FT-450D. Its rig control is sufficient that I don't generally have to turn back to my radio.

BTW, be careful about using the term software-defined radio. I understand you to mean you want software that lets you control the radio. The term software-defined radio more commonly refers to a radio that performs filtering and shaping functions in software rather than hardware. The FT-450D (and I believe the FT-450) is actually such a radio. The radio control you are asking for is commonly called "rig control" or some-times "rig-cat".

Answer (score 3):

Yaesu makes software like what you're looking for:
Go the yaesu.com and find the FT-450D page, click on the Files tab, and look for:
PCC-450 Software V1.13 and Reference Manual (07/18/14)

The PCC-450 software runs on Windows and connects to the radio over a serial port. You can drive nearly every feature of the radio. I find it easier to use this software than to go through the radio menus.

Comment: will do- just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, remote control is not only possible, but it is easy.

The FT-450D is not like a naked SDR.  It may be one internally, but it does not need a program like SDR# to operate it.

That being said, there is a great program available that allows the front panel of the radio to appear on your screen, and you can use the keyboard and mouse to control it via the USB cable that is used for the Must-Have ADMS-450 programming software.

[RT Systems Radio Programming Software and Cable ADMS-450-USB](https://www.dxengineering.com/parts/rtp-adms-450-usb) (DX Engineering)

With the USB Cable installed, run this software for on-screen remote control:

[PCC-450 Software V1.13 and Reference Manual (07/18/14)](https://www.yaesu.com/downloadFile.cfm?FileID=8352&FileCatID=42&FileName=PCC%2D450D%5FV102.zip&FileContentType=application%2Fx%2Dzip%2Dcompressed)  (Yaesu.com)

---

To see all of the Yaesu software and documentation for the FT-450D, click here and then select the Files button:

[Yaesu FT-450D](https://www.yaesu.com/indexVS.cfm?cmd=DisplayProducts&ProdCatID=102&encProdID=870B3CA7CFCB61E6A599B0EFEA2217E4)  (Yaesu.com)